# Why can't I connect to a wifi network with my laptop, when I can with my phone?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, connection

I can connect with my phone and use the browser as usual. On my laptop it won't connect when using windows 7 while in ubuntu it will connect, but with no internet.

What is going on here and how can I get internet on my laptop ?

[edit]

It's a public wifi hotspot. I can connect with no issues at home.
My network asapter is: Atheros AR5B97.
And my phone is an iPhone 3G. The wizard's of no help since it asks me to check the router, which I can't since it's a public hostspot.

[edit]

It works on ubuntu. Still doesn't connect on windows.

Comment: Need more information. What phone? What laptop? What are the network's settings (802.11 version, encryption used, etc.)? Can your laptop connect to other networks? Also, I'm not sure about Ubuntu, but Windows 7 has built-in troubleshooting wizards. Have you tried those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have static `IP` address on your laptop.

Check your adapter configs.

Comment: Nope, it obtains the address.

Comment: When your computer connects to wireless and it does not open page(as you said in ubuntu), it is something about your network adapter configs or firewall. Can you post your routing table here? And can you `ping 8.8.8.8` and tell me about the result? Thanks

Comment: It works on ubuntu now. I disconnected and reconnected to test the ping, but it works. I'm posting from ubuntu right now. It still doesn't connect on windows though.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your driver. Try uninstall it and install it again, after uninstalling reboot your system, I think this will work. Let me know about it. Good Luck

Comment: Installed the latest driver. It still won't connect on windows.

Comment: See you previous added networks, delete all of them, maybe your network is added before and something conflicts. If that does not help, assign static IP to your driver(See what IP it gives you in ubuntu) and try to connect, if that does not help again I just have 2 suggestions, 1. Some program you installed is conflicting with connectivity so find it and unistall it OR 2. Try reinstall your system.

Comment: Good ideas. I'll try them first thing in the morning.

Comment: Well, still no cake. I wouldn't reinstall my system since I reinstalled it recently and I don't think that would change anything. Still, something is strange about this network. In ubuntu, it connects automatically to this network now, but the internet doesn't work until I disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: I reinstalled and it works. Windows is certainly weird...

Answer (score 0):

Also, check since it is public, there may be a page that has not shown up, asking you to agree to terms of use. You may not see that and you will connect, but never see anything work. Possibly the iPhone is connecting, but is internet coming through that source? or maybe it is getting 3g too.